# Python scraping information has the same classes

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How do I return data from https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB. I am trying to pull the open and close data. The thing is that both of these numbers share the same class in the code.

They both share this class 'Trsdu(0.3s) '

How can I differentiate these if the classes are the same?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

goog = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB')

googsoup = BeautifulSoup(goog.text, 'html.parser')

googclose = googsoup.find(class_='Trsdu(0.3s) ').get_text()
```

Answer (score 2):

This function:

`googclose = googsoup.find(class_='Trsdu(0.3s) ').get_text()`

will return just the text of the first element with class `Trsdu(0.3s)`.

Using:

`googclose = googsoupsoup.find_all(class_='Trsdu(0.3s)')`

will return an array containing the page's elements with class  `Trsdu(0.3s)`.

Then you can iterate them:

`for element in googsoupsoup.find_all(class_='Trsdu(0.3s)'):
    print element.get_text()`

Answer (score 1):

Check this out, if this is what you wanted:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

goog = requests.get('https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/FB?p=FB')
googsoup = BeautifulSoup(goog.text, 'html.parser')
googclose = googsoup.select("span[data-reactid=42]")[1].text
googopen = googsoup.select("span[data-reactid=48]")[0].text
print("Close: {}\nOpen: {}".format(googclose,googopen))
```

Result:

```
Close: 172.17
Open: 171.69
```

Comment: There are two `close` in that page. 1. previous Close 2. At close. If you are after `Previous close` then my above code is right otherwise if you wanna get `At Close` then just change the index to 0. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the values for `Open` and `Previous Close`, you can either use `findAll` and grab the first 2 items in the results

```
googclose, googopen = googsoup.findAll('span', class_='Trsdu(0.3s) ')[:2]
googclose = googclose.get_text()
googopen = googopen.get_text()
print(googclose, googopen)

>>> 172.17 171.69
```

Or you can go one level higher, and find the values based on the parent `td` using the `data-test` attribute

```
googclose = googsoup.find('td', attrs={'data-test': 'PREV_CLOSE-value'}).get_text()
googopen = googsoup.find('td', attrs={'data-test': 'OPEN-value'}).get_text()
print(googclose, googopen)

>>> 172.17 171.69
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Chrome browser you can **right**-click on the item that you want to know more about then select *Inspect* from the resulting menu. The browser will show you something like this for the number associated with OPEN.

[image: OPEN code]

Notice that, not only is there a class attribute, there's the `data-reactid` attribute that might do the trick. In fact, if you also inspect the close number you will find, as I did, that its attribute is different.

This suggests the following code.

```
>>> import requests
>>> import bs4
>>> soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')
>>> soup.findAll('span', attrs={'data-reactid': '42'})[0].text
'172.17'
>>> soup.findAll('span', attrs={'data-reactid': '48'})[0].text
'171.69'
```